# Non static reference is giving NPE in OsgiCommandSupport for custom commands

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle

I am trying to implement custom command in Apache karaf version 2.3.10.

```
@Component
@Command (scope = "test", name = "list", description = "list all the test commands")
public class CustomCommand extends OsgiCommandSupport
{
...
    @Reference (bind = "bindMethod", unbind = "unbindMethod", cardinality = ReferenceCardinality.MANDATORY_UNARY, policy = ReferencePolicy.DYNAMIC)
    private SampleService mySampleService;
    ...

     protected void bindMethod(SampleService aSampleService)
    {
        mySampleService = aSampleService;
    }

    protected void unbindMethod(Services aSampleService)
    {
        mySampleService = null;
    }
     @Override
    protected Object doExecute() throws Exception
    {
        mySampleService.printCommands(); // nullpointer exception is thrown for non static sampleservice reference
        System.out.println("Command printed test:")
    }
}
```

After installing the bundle i am getting NPE for non static sampleservice reference. 
In bindServices the reference is resolved properly. If i change the Sampleservice to static then everything works fine.
What is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 0):

The reason probably is that there are two instances created for the class CustomCommand. One is created by felix scr and the other probably by blueprint.

If you use a static reference then the injection done by scr is visible for all instances. A static variable is not a good solution though as there is still a timing problem if the scr injection is done too late.

Karaf commands are not singletons. For each call to the command a new instance of CustomCommand is created. So creating commands using DS normally does not work.

Comment: Thanks Christian. I am not using blueprint. Could you please provide me a reference or description about the timing problem in scr injection. Is there any way to avoid static?

Comment: Christian I don't believe that's right. Why on earth can you not create a command using DS? It's just a service... admittedly I'm not a Karaf user but I create plain Gogo commands using DS all the time. I think this is actually a problem that the @Reference declaration is screwed up, look at the bind method name. Also it shouldn't be a dynamic reference.

Comment: In plain gogo it is easy as the command is a singleton. Karaf unfortunately uses a different model. The class the user implements is not the real command it is an Action. Karaf then instantiates one object for each call to the command. See https://github.com/apache/karaf/blob/karaf-2.3.x/shell/console/src/main/java/org/apache/karaf/shell/console/commands/BlueprintCommand.java

Comment: So Karaf doesn't support plain Gogo commands? One interesting behaviour of Gogo is that it gets the service from the ServiceReference each time you call the command, and then releases it. So with a default delayed DS component, you do see it bouncing up and down. You can modify that simply by setting immediate=true.

Comment: As far as I know karaf supports plain gogo commands but many of the karaf features then do not work. Like help and completion. 
Guillaume started working on better support but it is by far not complete. I tried to get the karaf team to switch to the gogo model for karaf 4 but was not succesful.

Comment: @Christian. I have just downloaded the apache-karaf-2.3.10 source code which consists of custom commands(WebListCommand). In that Service was used as a non static reference as mentioned above example. If karaf code works well why the above code gives NPE?.

Comment: Can you post a complete little example somewhere like on github? Btw. karaf 2.3 is quite old. Are you sure that your SCR version supports the style of annoations you use?

Answer (score 0):

Your @Reference declaration states that the bind method is named `bindMethod` but there is no such method on your class. Instead you have called it `bindServices`. Similarly the unbind method name is incorrect.

Also there is no need to use the dynamic reference policy.

Comment: sorry it's my mistake. Its typo error. it works fine as i said with static reference..May be i will check with static policy.

Comment: Okay then it's probably the dynamic policy. There is a race condition... because you specified dynamic, the service reference can be injected after the activation of the component.

Comment: You also don't need a unbind method.

Comment: Why not? Did you try? What happens?

Comment: i have changed policy = ReferencePolicy.DYNAMIC to policy = ReferencePolicy.STATIC. and without static reference(private SampleService mySampleService). Still it gives NPE

Comment: Please verify (using a debugger or System.out.println) that your bind method is invoked and your unbind method is *not* invoked.

Comment: Yes. Bind method is invoked and unbind is not invoked1

Comment: Then I suspect that Karaf is creating a separate instance of your class from the DS component. It doesn't look like you can use DS injection in that case, which is pretty much what Christian said. I will have to defer to him because I only know base OSGi, not Karaf.